# Cxf Transformation Feature: How to change a specific element?

Tags: java, cxf

Using the transformation feature with, for example key = {ns}tag, value ={ns}Tag will transform all "tag" elements of the xml to "Tag"elements.

```
<parent>
  <tag...>
  <child>
    <tag...>
  </child>
</parent>
```

Let's say I only want to modify the "tag" element of child not of parent.
How can I modify a specific element?

Comment: Maybe using the [XSLT feature](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/xslt-feature.html) is an option?

Comment: The transformation feature is already implemented, so it would be nice if the problem above also could be solved with it. I'm not familar with the xslt feature or xslt itself, so it would take too much time to get this feature working(in my opinion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's not possible to achieve this with the CXF Transformation Feature. I don't have the time to achieve this with the CXF XSLT Feature, so I decided to create my own interceptor which uses a XPath Expression to solve this.

Comment: Yes i believe that for long XML response messages, it;s better to create a interceptor and you can handle the same in filters also. I got it working by creating a cxf filter.